# I get the a Firebase Error: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage' - exceeded the quota

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I get the a Firebase Error: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage' - exceeded the quota.

I'm on the blaze plan so I shouldn't get this error.

This occurs on login with social media e.g. facebook.
Works fine in firefox but I got this error in chrome and chrome is the browser I commonly use.

**This is the exact console error message:**

```
app.js?1480624277794:36 Error: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'firebase:session::mywebsite' exceeded the quota.
    at vc.g.set (firebase.js:13)
    at wg.set (firebase.js:52)
    at Wg (firebase.js:61)
    at Object.eval [as zc] (firebase.js:60)
    at eval (firebase.js:77)
    at Kh.g.Id (firebase.js:78)
    at yh.Id (firebase.js:75)
    at qh.eval [as zg] (firebase.js:74)
    at th (firebase.js:70)
    at WebSocket.ua.onmessage (firebase.js:70)
```

Comment: Hey AngularM, what version of Firebase SDK are you using. Make sure you use the latest version 3.6. This error occurs either when you have web storage disabled or when you actually exceed your quota for web storage (you are storing too many things in web storage). Try to test in the console by saving some web storage data: window.localStorage.setItem('key', 'value'). Check if you get the same error.

Comment: I'm using an older version, but I cant upgrade because lots of my code will stop working

Comment: Only way I can get rid of this error is my clearer my cache in the browser. However, I don't want my customers to do this. Any other suggestions?

Comment: This seems specific to your browser. You must have added some 3rd party/cookie restrictions in your browser, or you have exceeded your web storage quote.

Comment: this may be due to some kind of your browser extension

Comment: I have the same issue on almost every device in our company. Very anoying to tell ppl how to delete the cache. And yes probably the storage is exceeded but can't the SDk catch the error and not throw the whole application to break -.-